# How to do an actual file upload with phpunit and Laravel that's not fake

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

Phpunit, Laravel 5.5 
How do I emulate, not fake, an actual file upload with phpunit and Laravel. My latest stab at it is like this.  From the unit test:

```
$handle = fopen($path,'r');
$content = fread($handle,2048);
fclose($handle);
$fdata = [
  'delimiter'           => '3',
  'id'                  => 1,
  'allow_shared_roles'  => 'on',
  'file'=>$name
];
$this->call('POST','/event/add-wizard/2',$fdata,[],[],[
    'Content-Length'=>strlen($content),
    'Content-Type'=>'multipart/form-data;boundary='.$content,
    'Content-Disposition'=>'form-data;name="file";filename="'.$name.'"'
  ],$content);
```

Then on the server side, this is where I get hung up.

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    $input['extension'] = strtolower($request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension());
}
$validator = \Validator::make($input, ['file' => 'required', 'extension' => 'in:csv', 'delimiter' => 'required'], ['extension.in' => 'The file must be a .csv file.']);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return \Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
}

if (!file_exists(storage_path('temp-files'))) {
    \File::makeDirectory(storage_path('temp-files'));
}

$date = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

$tmpFile = $request->file('file')->move(storage_path('temp-files'), $date->format('YmdHis') . '_' . $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName());
```

Then I get move on null error on the last line shown.

Having never done this kind of thing before I admit I'm stabbing in the dark. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ask yourself why you want to test this as you mentioned? You can mock the `File` component because it's a vendor component, it's already tested by the vendor (assumption!!). So if those methods are called with the right parameters then you can assume the scenario works.. Or do you don't trust your vendor?Otherwise it may belongs to an e2e test imo..

Comment: As I've never mocked a file before, this may be a stupid question, but can I mock a file with specific content? And will that help me test the server routine? I don't really care about the file but the routine that it gets passed to.

Answer (score 0):

After confirming in the comments that you want to check if the upload routine is being followed instead really uploading a file you can mock the facade `File` to see if the methods are called and with the right parameters (optional).

To mock a Facade in Laravel you can use the build in `shouldReceive('method_name')` method. In your situation you can add this before the call:

```
// should create new directory
File::shouldReceive('makeDirectory')
                    ->once();

// should move the uploaded file to the dir
File::shouldReceive('move')
                    ->once()
                    ->andReturn( $fake_file );
```

You can read more about mocking facades [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mocking#mocking-facades).